# Screen Object not found

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Project in Excel.  I have a module with sub Load to populate the ActiveForm with data in an Excel table that is tagged to go into that respective form.  The idea is that whichever Form is active, I can call Load and get the data from the Excel table.

I am trying to use this simple code to get the name of the active form, like I have seen in so many examples

```
Debug.Print Screen.activeform.Name
```

However, the Screen object cannot be found.  I get "Variable Not Defined" error. 
 Is this something that can be added via references?  I have searched high and low.  Or, can I pass a reference to the "Me" to the module?

Here is the code I have in the module to populate whichever form the user opens:

```
Public Sub Load()

Dim rw As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsInputs = wb.Worksheets("Inputs")
Set loInputs = wsInputs.ListObjects("tInputs")

With loInputs
    For rw = 1 To .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
        If .ListColumns("Form").DataBodyRange.Rows(rw) = screen.activeform Then
            screen.activeform.Controls(.ListColumns("Control Name").DataBodyRange.Rows(rw).Value) _
            = .ListColumns("Value").DataBodyRange.Rows(rw).Value
        End If
    Next rw
End With

End Sub
```

The different forms are just different categories of data for input into text and combo boxes that read back and forth from the form to Excel, of if there is data in Excel and the user opens that form, it is pre-populated.

I can include a screenshot but its just a bunch of labels and input boxes.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this an Access VBA object? What do you want to get? In Excel, you could use Me.Name if a form is active in most cases.

Comment: `Screen` is a thing in VB6, not in VBA.

Comment: I'm curious about *why* you would ever even *need* to get the active form though. How are you displaying that form? Is it modal? There are multiple modeless instances of a form that are visible and you're trying to get the topmost one? Please clarify. Feel free to include a screenshot of the forms so we can get a better idea of what you're looking at.

Comment: Apparently `Screen.ActiveForm` is a thing in Access. Note that it returns an *Access Form*, not a `UserForm`. In any case without seeing more of your code (in particular, how the forms are displayed), I doubt you'll get a useful answer.

Comment: This seems to be an XY problem

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work by having the function accept the form as a parameter:

```
Public Sub LoadData(frmLoad As Object)
```

And simply pass Me to the function:

```
LoadData Me
```

Perhaps the is poor design but it works.  And therefor I don't need to include the LoadData function in each form.

Matt

Comment: If you would have included the code that displays the form as I asked, we could have helped with the poor design. By all means read the article I linked to in my last comment to your question - it's possibly a bit advanced stuff, but it should help you wrap your head around form instances, and avoid common traps related to dealing with forms' default instances. That said passing `Me` works just fine - the design problem IMO is that your form seems to be running the show.